# Nested dicts with empty lists to Pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some data from an API that I am trying to convert to a Pandas dataframe.
I am struggling to extract the 'station_xyz__cr' id number from the list in a nested dict (where a list can be empty as in the middle dataset).

```
output = {'data': [{'abc_serial_number__c': 'ABC2020-07571',
       'id': 'V48000000000F79',
       'modified_date__v': '2020-06-15T05:13:14.000Z',
       'name__v': 'VVV-001039',
       'station_xyz__cr': {'data': [{'id': 'V5J000000000B86'}],
                           'responseDetails': {'limit': 250,
                                               'offset': 0,
                                               'size': 1,
                                               'total': 1}}},
      {'abc_serial_number__c': 'ABC2020-09952',
       'id': 'V48000000001B94',
       'modified_date__v': '2020-06-24T11:30:40.000Z',
       'name__v': 'VVV-004040',
       'station_xyz__cr': {'data': [],
                           'responseDetails': {'limit': 250,
                                               'offset': 0,
                                               'size': 1,
                                               'total': 1}}},
      {'abc_serial_number__c': 'ABC2020-09196',
       'id': 'V48000000001B95',
       'modified_date__v': '2020-06-23T09:38:18.000Z',
       'name__v': 'VVV-004041',
       'station_xyz__cr': {'data': [{'id': 'V5J000000000Z10'}],
                           'responseDetails': {'limit': 250,
                                               'offset': 0,
                                               'size': 1,
                                               'total': 1}}}],
 'responseDetails': {'limit': 1000, 'offset': 0, 'size': 3, 'total': 3},
 'responseStatus': 'SUCCESS'}
```

I'm trying to get the nested id data into a column in the dataframe something like this:

```
   station_xyz__cr.data.id
0          V5J000000000B86
1                     None 
2          V5J000000000Z10
```

I've tried converting to a dataframe with json_normalize (droppping the columns I don't need):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(output['data'])
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.startswith('station_xyz__cr.responseDetails')]
print(df)

  abc_serial_number__c               id          modified_date__v     name__v  \
0        ABC2020-07571  V48000000000F79  2020-06-15T05:13:14.000Z  VVV-001039   
1        ABC2020-09952  V48000000001B94  2020-06-24T11:30:40.000Z  VVV-004040   
2        ABC2020-09196  V48000000001B95  2020-06-23T09:38:18.000Z  VVV-004041   

          station_xyz__cr.data  
0  [{'id': 'V5J000000000B86'}]  
1                           []  
2  [{'id': 'V5J000000000Z10'}]
```

but Im stuggling to convert the 'station_xyz__cr.data' list of dicts to simple dataframe of the ids:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['station_xyz__cr.data'].tolist(), index= df.index)
df2 = df2.rename(columns = {0:'station_xyz__cr.data'})
df2

        station_xyz__cr.data
0  {'id': 'V5J000000000B86'}
1                       None
2  {'id': 'V5J000000000Z10'}
```

The 'None' is causing me problems when I tried to extract further.
I tried replacing the None - but I could only replace with 0:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: what do you want instead of None? why not just apply a lambda after the fact to pull out the id from ur current result

Comment: @Derek Eden Thanks. I used your suggestion successfully: `df2['station_xyz__cr.data']=df2['station_xyz__cr.data'].map(lambda x : x[0]['id'] if x else None)`

Answer (score 1):

Get the row index of None values. Using row index as a mask, set the row, col combinations to a default value that is consistent with the rest of the columns' values for next stage in data flow.

```py
isna_idx = pd.isnull(df2['station_xyz__cr.data'])
df2.loc[isna_idx, ['station_xyz__cr.data']] = {'id': '...'}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I try and put the dict per your suggestion it results in NaN as below:
`            station_xyz__cr.data`
`    0  {'id': 'V5J000000000B86'}`
`    1                        NaN`
`    2  {'id': 'V5J000000000Z10'}`
putting a string 'foo' works.

Comment: Didn't expect that... Maybe confirm the dtype of the column is 'object'? `DataFrame.dtypes` Dtype as object will allow you to assign a dict object as value for that cell. Should already be that dtype based on your example though.